# Why Webstorm favorites not working

Tags: webstorm

When I add file to favorite list, it do not appear there.
If i choose add to new favorite list, list gets created, with file in it. But i can not add other file to that list, as well as to default list, though new list appears in list of options to which favorite to add file.
Im using webstorm 11 on os x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Webstorm favorites not working

Because there is a bug (affects all IDEs, not just WebStorm).

[It's fixed now](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143478) -- you should see it working again in WebStorm 11.0.2 (I think).

---

**P.S.**
Looks like devs somehow broke working feature and had no time (were unable to acknowledge this?) to fix it for almost 3 months...

Comment: Thats right. Fixed with update (webstorm -> check for updates). Pretty obvious.